# When Input data give newline problem need to strip the newline one by one

Tags: python, input

I Have data to copy to text editor :

- John
- Emma
- Rick
- Eva

When I copy to python text editor :

```
name = "- John
- Emma
- Rick
- Eva"
```

I need to copy to text editor like this :

```
name = "John Emma Rick Eva"
```

I looked to website or stackoverflow but they just give me information about newline ("\n") and this is different. This problem need like excel or something? Any insight will be very helpful. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Are you just trying to format your clipboard to remove newlines and `-` so you can paste it into your text editor?

Comment: yeah, but not the newline "/n Hello /n" , but the newline to copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste it into a string with triple quotes (`name = """here"""` ; to preserve newline), and use regex to remove the unwanted charaters:

```
import re

name = """- John
- Emma
- Rick
- Eva"""

name = re.sub("- (.+)\n?", "\g<1> ", name).strip()
```

```
>>> name
'John Emma Rick Eva'
```

You can copy it from here, or just keep it as is (name is now in the form you wanted).

> Online regex demo https://regex101.com/library/owvfGh

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful!! I shouldn't delete the newlines again :D

Comment: No worries :). Check out [this website](https://regexone.com/) to learn some regex if you're interested. Also, I added `import re` to the answer if that helps